# Пропали подсказки в последней версии Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Раньше были подсказки для kotlin'а, а сейчас всё пропало. Подскажите как вернуть. Переустановка не помогла, видимо настройки сохранились где-то.

Comment: Какого рода подсказки были?

Comment: Пишу код, появляется подсказка с возможными вариантами, выбираю нужный, нажимаю tab и предложенный вариант прописывается

Comment: Попробуйте что-то из этого: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18370599/3212712

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй File > Invalidate Caches / Restart > Invalidate and Restart

Если не помогло перезапусти студию и посмотри строку состояния внизу, возможно включён Power Safe mode, его нужно отключить (по клику перейдёшь в нужный сегмент где будет кнопка отключения). Понимаю, что ты за год уже разобрался, но может другим поможет)